# curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL every second request

Tags: ssl, curl

Currently I have extremely strange behavior of curl. When I do `curl https://developer.here.com/ -iv` once, it responds fine with code 200 and text/html content, but immediately after that with second request it says this:

```
*   Trying 18.194.70.125...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to developer.here.com (18.194.70.125) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to developer.here.com:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to developer.here.com:443
```

On the third request it responds successfully and fails on fourth and so on. How is this possible?

Comment: This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48987512/3395469) might be worth a look. For potential clarification on Kaspersky, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182025/openssl-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-raw-githubusercontent-com443).